# how to include pl files in batch pod conversion?

Tags: perl

I use the module [Pod::Simple::HTMLBatch](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod%3a%3aSimple%3a%3aHTMLBatch) to create the documentation of the software which i write.

The script used is taken from the documentation:

```
use Pod::Simple::HTMLBatch;
my $batchconv = Pod::Simple::HTMLBatch->new;
$batchconv->some_option( some_value );
$batchconv->some_other_option( some_other_value );
$batchconv->batch_convert( \@search_dirs, $output_dir );
```

The module just considers pm files. How is it possible to tell  the module to create the documentation also for pl files?

I did not find an option in the documentation.

Comment: This is funny. In the ask me section it is written "If you want to do some kind of big pod-to-HTML version with some particular kind of option that you don't see how to achieve using this module, email me (sburke@cpan.org) and I'll probably have a good idea how to do it." A couple of lines afterwards it is written "Pod::Simple was created by Sean M. Burke <sburke@cpan.org>. But don't bother him, he's retired." Should i bother him or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pod::Simple::Search looks for files [matching this regular expression](https://github.com/theory/pod-simple/blob/master/lib/Pod/Simple/Search.pm#L175):

```
m/^[-_a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(?:pod|pm|plx?)\z/is
```

Which should include any `*.pl` files. If it's not working for you, try turning on its laborious flag, which is somewhat more forgiving about file names, testing like so:

```
m/\.(pod|pm|plx?)\z/i || -x _ and -T _
```

The only way to enable the laborious search with Pod::Simple::HTMLBatch is to create a search subclass, like I did for [Pod::Site](https://metacpan.org/module/Pod%3a%3aSite):

```
package My::Pod::Search;
use parent 'Pod::Simple::Search';
sub new {
    my $self = shift->SUPER::new(@_);
    $self->laborious(1);
    return $self;
}
```

Then tell HTMLBatch to use your subclass:

```
$batchconv->search_class('My::Pod::Search');
$batchconv->batch_convert( \@search_dirs, $output_dir );
```

Might be nice to update HTMLBatch to accept a search object in its constructor to eliminate this silly workaround, though.